# How to show picture in Android app that can be changed every week? Like flyer for specials that changes every week

Tags: android, image

I'm working/learning on an app for my store. The whole purpose of this app is to a customer can check recent flyer in the app.

How can I replace that image every week? how does update on app (like image change) works? Does customer need to update the app in order to see new image? or is there any way where my app will fetch photo from "XYZ" location online, and all I have to do is upload that image online to "XYZ" location.

Comment: Have the image stored on an SQL server over the internet, save the image you want to display to the database, and then have the app read the image from there

Comment: this is exactly what i was wondering, but wasn't sure if i can do that. Thank you so much for your answer.

Comment: No worries, just save the image using binary, using  stream and you should be good to go.

Comment: use Firebase config.

Comment: Whatever you do, you should use some functionality to cache image, and download only if there is a new image available. No reason to keep downloading same image again and again. You might want to look into using the "eTag" header.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest showing your weekly image from a URL like this

```
ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
try {
    URL url = new URL("http://web.yourcompany.com/weekly.jpg");
    HttpGet httpRequest = null;

    httpRequest = new HttpGet(url.toURI());

    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) httpclient.execute(httpRequest);

    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    BufferedHttpEntity b_entity = new BufferedHttpEntity(entity);
    InputStream input = b_entity.getContent();

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);

    img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

} catch (Exception ex) {
}
```

or using the [`WebView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) to load the image from URL.

```
WebView web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
web.loadUrl("Your/Url.jpg");
```

Ideally, you want to call this code from a separate thread.